# Making a path transparant on another path, Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I looked on this site (and other sites) for my answer but I couldn't find it. If it is here, I am sorry.

My problem is I made something and I want to print it on a bag. It is a city, outlined, and filled with black. And the streets and lakes are filled with white. Both on different layers. But if I am going to print it, the streets and lakes have to be transparant, so the color of the bag will come through it. But I just can't find out how to do it. Any suggestions?

(The streets/lakes are all individual paths, grouped together, the map itself is one path.)

[image: The design itself.]
[image: How it is ordered.]

Thanks in advance! 
Kelly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select everything on your 'streets' layer.
- Go to `Object > Path > Outline Stroke`
- Open the Pathfinder window (with everything on that layer still selected) and hit `Unite`
- Select the newly created, united shape *and* the shape on your 'map'
  layer
- In the Pathfinder window hit `Minus Front`

Done.

Comment: one can keep them editable by usinf knockout groups..

Comment: @joojaa: True, but I'm trying to keep it simple. Maybe add your suggested method as an alternative answer?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming all your roads are on a single layer and you want them all to be transparent (if not just group them and do the same to the group instead):

1. Select the layer in the layers panel
2. Set Opacity to "0%"
3. Check "Page Knockout Group" in the Transparency panel menu

[image]

Regular [Knockout groups](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Badobe-illustrator%5D+knockout+group) are great for creating transparency and keeping everything editable; *Page* knockout groups are good for things like this since they knockout *everything*.